# The setIcon method does not work because of NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

When using the method to change the background of the interface it gives an error, even though I invoked the necessary libraries and the methods are correctly written,

```
ImageIcon wallpaper = new ImageIcon("src/images/wallpaperPrincipal.jpg");
        Icon icono = new ImageIcon(wallpaper.getImage().getScaledInstance(jLabel_Wallpaper.getWidth(),
                jLabel_Wallpaper.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        jLabel_Wallpaper.setIcon(icono);
        this.repaint();
```

marks the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setIcon(javax.swing.Icon)
  location: variable jLabel_Wallpaper of type java.awt.Label
    at ventanas.informacionUsuario.<init>(informacionUsuario.java:181)
    at ventanas.informacionUsuario$1.run(informacionUsuario.java:183)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Until now what I did was to delete the class and redo it (copying and pasting the previous code) and sometimes I would get the error again and at other times the program would work fine. I got annoyed with it and I want to find a solution that does not involve redoing the class.

It just shows me the error line, in some classes it works fine and in others it shows the error, and the problem has happened to me a couple of times.

Comment: 1. Clean and build, could be old cached data; 2. Don't reference `src` in your code, this won't exist once the app is built and exported, use `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/wallpaperPrincipal.jpg"))` instead. Infact you should probably be using `new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/wallpaperPrincipal.jpg"))` at least this way, of the image can't be read, it will throw an exception

Comment: *And* you need to put the images [in the right place](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)